# can I convert column data type in array from string to int?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to compare values between two String arrays and calculate the repeated words 
I created Two-dimensional array :
1st dimension : contains all words ,
2nd dimension : contains counter ;
To do that i want to convert data type of 2nd dimension from String to int
to calculate the Repetition .
Can I do this Conversion ????

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace change
{
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       // int counter = 1;

        String [] arr =  {"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","ddd","bbb"}  ;
        String[] arr2 = { "a", "bb", "ccc", "dd", "aaa", "fff", "ooo" };


        String[,] wordsAndCounter = new string[arr.Length, 2]; // matrix contains [words, counter] . I want to convert counter datatype to int to calculate the repeated words .

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
            wordsAndCounter[i, 0] = arr[i];


        //    Console.WriteLine(wordsAndCounter[i,0]);
        //    Console.WriteLine(wordsAndCounter[i, 1]);

            String x= arr[i];
            String y = arr2[i];

        //    for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++) {

                if (x.Equals(y))


              //  {
                    counter++;
                    wordsAndCounter[i, 1] = "counter"; // i want to convert this "counter" to int 
                 //   Console.WriteLine(wordsAndCounter[i, 1]);
                 //   Console.WriteLine(counter);
                }
                else {

                    wordsAndCounter[i, 1] = "counter"; // i want to convert this "counter" to int 
                  //  Console.WriteLine(wordsAndCounter[i, 1]);
                   // Console.WriteLine(counter);
                }

            }

        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

}
    }

Comment: Why not using Dictionary type to save the result like IDictionary<string, int> result = new Dictionary<string, int>();

Comment: Is this Dictionary type allow me to store unlimited values as dynamic array , i dont know how to control my columns and rows in dictionary type & allow me to check my equal-values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert from string to int you can always use [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or (even better) [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But in your example you defined string array, so you actually need backward cast - so you can use `ToString()`. The downside of your approach is that lack of flexibility -you want to have integers, not strings thus you can use dinamic objects or generic dictionary/list of tuples/whatever. Here is a short LINQ solution with dynamic objects:

```
String [] arr =  {"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","ddd","bbb"}  ;
String[] arr2 = { "a", "bb", "ccc", "dd", "aaa", "fff", "ooo" };

var list = arr.Select(a => new {Word = a, WordCount = arr2.Count(a2 => a2 == a)}).ToList();
list.ForEach(el => Console.WriteLine(el.Word + "  " + el.WordCount));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want:

```
static void Main()
{
    int counter = 1;

    String [] arr =  {"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","ddd","bbb"}  ;
    String[] arr2 = { "a", "bb", "ccc", "dd", "aaa", "fff", "ooo" };

    Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int> ();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
    {
        wordsAndCounter[i, 0] = arr[i];
        string x = arr[i];
        string y = arr2[i];

        if (x.Equals(y)) {
            if (dict.ContainsKey(x)) {
                ++dict[x];
            } else {
                dict[x] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (var el in dict) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", el.Key, el.Value);
    }
}
```